# How can you change the color of a jinja2 entry depending on some condition? (using flask)

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

I just worked through the [flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/), step by step creating a blog web application. The entries are rendered via a jinja template:

```
<ul class=entries>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.text|safe }}
    {% else %}
        <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

The color is defined in a style.css:

```
a, h1, h2       { color: #377ba8; }
```

However, I really would like to be able, to switch the color of the entry depending on a condition. For example, if the entry.text is 'apples', it should be red, otherwise green.

Being a bloody noob to web development, I feel like something like this might be javascript, but I simply don't see how to accomplish this task and would appreciate your help.

Best,

gbrown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should add a rule to your CSS so that you can change the color by applying a class to your element. Something like this:

```css
.apples {
    color: red;
}
```

Then, you need to make your Jinja template apply a `class` attribute depending on the value of `entry.text`:

```html
<ul class="entries">
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li {% if entry.text == 'apples' %} class="apples" {% endif %}>
            <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
            {{ entry.text|safe }}
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>
            <em>Unbelievable. No entries here so far.</em>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This technique is described in the Jinja manual for example under the topic [“Highlighting Active Menu Items”](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items).

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!